# Throw IOException in actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) method

Tags: java

I am trying to create a guessing game program for my online course, where there are a bunch of questions and you are able to answer them, but I have come to the point in my program where I am having some difficulties...

Now, what I am trying to do is read a file from an "actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)" method, then display if the users answer is right...

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class allQuestions implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        if(event.getActionCommand().equals("Answer M 100"))
        {
            try
            {
                File answersFile = new File("answers_file.txt");
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(answersFile);
                if(sc.hasNext("1000000"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Your answer is correct!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Your answer is wrong.");
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("File cannot load.");
            }
        }
    }


    public static void math100()
    {
        JFrame m100Frame = new JFrame("100 Point Math Question");
        m100Frame.setSize(350,350);
        m100Frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        m100Frame.setContentPane(pane);

        JLabel question = new JLabel("<html><p><div WIDTH = 320><center>Round 1,000,203 to the nearest thousands, and round 8.472 to the nearest hundredth.</p><p>Put answers in box below, and have the word 'and' between the two answers.</center></width></div></html>");

        JTextArea answer = new JTextArea("Enter Answers Here", 10, 25);

        JButton answerQuestion = new JButton("Answer M 100");

        answerQuestion.addActionListener(new allQuestions());

        pane.add(question);
        pane.add(answer);
        pane.add(answerQuestion);

        m100Frame.setVisible(true);
        m100Frame.toFront();
    }
}
```

Now I dunno what I have done wrong, but I am trying to just make it so that when a user types their answer into the box, and you hit enter, it scans the file to see if their answer is right, then displays if its right or wrong...

Hope this explains it a bit. Thanks for the help.

Comment: IOException = problem with the file. Does it exist? In which folder?

Comment: You should tag the question with `java`, not `javascript`.

Comment: Theirry, I have the file in the folder that it needs to be, but I keep getting the error saying that it needs to throw IOException, yet it won't allow me to add that to the actionPerformed method...

Comment: Are you compiling it, or is that what the online course 'bot' is telling you?

Comment: Its tells me to compile it. Its really hard to explain. like I am suppose to create an application that is an educational guessing game, so I am making a game where you click specific buttons for specific questions, when you click a specific question, it is suppose to display the question and a text box. In the text box, you are suppose to answer the question, then hit the button to answer the question. It then goes to the file I created and searches for the answer you entered, and then displays if the answer is correct or not. But it isn't working right for me.

Comment: Your code compiles just fine for me.  The reason you have to catch the exception instead of throwing it is because you're overriding a method in the interface and that method signature does not throw an Exception.  If the problem is that it's printing "File cannot load" instead of "Your answer is correct/wrong." then it is not finding answers_file.txt.  You could try moving it or providing the absolute path.

Comment: Yeah, it does compile for me as well, and it does say "File cannot load". I put the directory of the file straight to where the file is, but it still does not work...Does it have something to do with the JTextArea? Like, is it not reading whats in the area and then it just goes straight to file cannot load?

Answer (score 0):

Your file `answers_file.txt` is not being found. Add the following line of debug code to see where your program is actually expecting the file to be.

```
File answersFile = new File("answers_file.txt"); // existing line
System.out.println(answersFile.getAbsolutePath()); // new debugging line
```

Also look very closely at the spelling of the filename in the code versus the actual filename on disk.

And remember backslash `\` is the String escape character in Java, so if you use backslashes in a file path you have to escape it like this:

```
String path = "C:\\folder\\file.txt";
```

Finally, if you're still having the problem, add this line of debug code to your `catch` block so you can see the exact error message:

```
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File cannot load."); // existing line
            e.printStackTrace(); // new debugging line
        }
```

With regard to throwing `IOException` from `ActionListener.actionPerformed()` - that is not allowed because IOException is a *checked exception* and is not declared to be thrown in the interface method declaration.

Comment: Hmmm....Didn't seem to work....Like what I am trying to do is make it so that the JTextArea reads the number that the user inputs, then they hit a button that is on that frame, it then sends it over to the actionPerformed method to check and see if the number that the user entered is in the file, and if it is then it displays that the answer entered is correct, but I cannot get that to happen. Every time I try to make this work, it says the file cannot be found...

Comment: I have answered your question "Throw IOException in actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) method". Please see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you want better answers. You are making your program print the string "File cannot load." for every possible IOException, when that may not be the correct explanation. For the real reason behind the error, include the full exception stack trace in your question.